# multiple file uploads using HTML5 for stuts 1

Tags: java, html, struts, struts-1

I tried to use HTML5 attribute multiple ="multiple" . I was able to select multiple files(ctrl+click) in FF. But this attribute is not working on IE 8. I have few questions regarding this behaviour

1) Is there any JS API which could allow this on IE.
2) Even though i select multiple files in FF , I am only seeing the latest file which was selected in the mulipart data on the server side. I am using Struts Form File for upload.

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, IE8 does not allow you to select multiple files. Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vapocalypse/LNYRG/) in IE8.

What you can do is to use Flash, when IE8 is detected. I've used [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) in the past and it is very reliable.

Cheers,
Apoc

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick response. I have tried using uploadify...but I am not allowed to use it for some security reasons...Also upon some digging i have seen that multiple attribute is not supported by IE even the latest ones.

Comment: Hey Apoc..Did u try and integrate Uploadify with struts action class..if so could you send share that piece of code...

Comment: What Uploadify does is a regular file upload. You must treat it at the server side in the same way of an upload done via a file input. See if this helps: http://www.roseindia.net/struts/strutsfileupload.shtml